# Reduce Logs from Preparing Environment in GitLab CI

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed some gitlab runners onto an EKS cluster and noticed that when an influx of jobs comes in and the cluster has to scale to meet the new demand the pods will sit and wait to create which is 100% expected but while the job is waiting, in the `Prepare environment` section of the runner log is spammed with logs like `ContainersNotReady: "containers with unrady status [build helper]"` A couple logs would be fine but I have jobs where logs like this occur 300 times. Makes the job log pretty dirty. Is there a way to modify the log level of only the preparing environment step or silence these specific logs?